# How to import @NonNull class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**I have to import @NonNull but can not find out using Alt+Enter in Windows, what steps have to do to import @NonNull class in java.**

```
private Toaster(@NonNull Context context) {
    weakReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
}

public static Toaster getInstance(@NonNull Context context) {
    if (toaster == null) {
        toaster = new Toaster(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return toaster;
}
```

[Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikd2U.png)

Comment: Independent of the question. If you are using the application context, then there shouldn't need to use a weak reference. You can't leak an application context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings > Keymap > Find 'Alt+Enter'.

[image]

Comment: I can't find it, recheck my post i upload SS on it

Comment: I have changed the image pls check it

Comment: I just need to know, how i import @NonNull class in my project.